# Latin Squares in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In the following $2$ part question I have answer part $1$ but I am a little confused how to use this to answer part $2$, looking for some help thanks!

> Suppose that two orthogonal $4x4$ Latin Squares both have $1,2,3,4$ as the main diagonal. Is it possible for both of them to have the same $(2,3)$ entry?

My Solution:

the order along the main diagonal is also matched between the two squares, in which case the answer to the opening question is naturally "no", since paired entries $(1\;1),$ $(2\;2),$ $(3\;3),$ $(4\;4)$ already exist and another matching pair would thus break orthogonality.

**Here is the question I am not sure how to answer**

> What does this answer tell you about the number of $4x4$ MOLS each of which has $1 2 3 4$ as the main diagonal?

Does this mean there is no $4x4$ MOLS with $1 2 3 4 $ as the main diagonal?

Comment: The $(2,3)$ of any latin square with $1234$ diagonal cannot be either $2$ or $3$. That leaves ... how many alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(2,3)$ entry of a Latin square with $1,2,3,4$ on the diagonal cannot be $2$ or $3$, so it can only be $1$ or $4$.  This shows there are at most two mutually orthogonal Latin squares with $1,2,3,4$ on the diagonal.  You can just fill in the two possibilities and complete the squares.
$$1342\quad\quad 1423\\4213\quad\quad 3241\\2431\quad\quad 4132\\3124\quad\quad 2314$$
Now check that they are in fact orthogonal.  I glanced and didn't see a problem.  This shows that there are exactly two MOLS with $1,2,3,4$ on the diagonal.

Comment: great answer, thanks!